# groupby.apply method taking more than one arguments

Tags: python-xarray

In `xarray` document, the `groupby.apply` method can apply some function to different groups. As in the documentation,

```
In [11]: def standardize(x):
   ....:     return (x - x.mean()) / x.std()
   ....: 

In [12]: arr.groupby('letters').apply(standardize)
```

However, how can I put another argument into the standardize function? i.e.

```
 def standardize(x, y):
   ....:     return (x - x.mean()) / x.std() + y.sum()
arr.groupby('letters').apply(standardize(x, y))??
```

It is obvious not right. 
Now, there is no way to call the apply method.

Comment: you could also use a functool.partial to get a new function with the y value filled in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To apply an operation over multiple variables at once, put multiple `DataArray` objects together into a single `xarray.Dataset`, e.g.,

```
# foo and bar are xarray.DataArray objects
ds = xarray.Dataset({'x': foo, 'y': bar})

def standardize(ds):
    return (ds.x - ds.x.mean()) / ds.x.std() + ds.y.sum()

ds.groupby('letters').apply(standardize)
```